# Why is HttpClient failing in Unity?

Tags: unity, .net, http

Before starting, I know I can use the UnityWebRequest class instead. The problem is that it is *another* library the one that is failing: NEthereum's source code, which makes heavy use of the HttpClient.

So I tried this in a behaviour (2021.3.25):

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using UnityEngine;

public class SampleBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        TestHttp();
    }

    private async void TestHttp()
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8545");
        await client.GetAsync("/").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

(I tried other local addresses, like my LAN ones, considering that http server is attending on 0.0.0.0 and I succeed hitting it with cURL)

**BUT** when I try this, I get this exception:

`SocketException: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used`

Now, the issue is that I use IPv4 in a daily basis in other places. What's wrong? Is it something in the .NET setup in the current Unity version? (I'm using .NET Framework and, again, 2021.3.25)

More context here:

I made this test in Unity:

[image: the new code]

*And still* get the error:

[image: same address error]

While a stand-alone .NET Framework console application does not fail like this:

[image: standalone app]

And, more important: This HttpClient-related things were working before. This happened after moving to a newer version of Unity (the 2021.3.25 I'm using now). This is why I'm posting the question here and not in a pure C#-related site.

Comment: This is a general question about .NET, not about game development, and doesn't belong here. As for a possible solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438416/why-is-httpclient-baseaddress-not-working

Comment: Dude, most likely if I state this in stackoverflow they'll lead me here because this is, in particular, a matter of the .NET platform that is embedded in the Unity version in particular.

Comment: I only have right now a 2021.1.15f version, but the code you posted results in NotImplementedException for the SslProtocols. Removing the constructor and not assigning the protocol at all, I'm getting a response when you assign the await as response and read it like `var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: Your code works for me as-is in Unity 2021.3.29f1, so maybe you should update from your very outdated version to the latest version. But as per the article I linked, it's best for the slash to be at the end of the base address (or at least that used to be the case).

Comment: I'll try later with that version. You might be right. I'll keep this question up to date.

Comment: Just added the trailing slash and nothing happened. I'll update the Unity version in some hrs and keep this up to date.

Comment: Note that you don't need to separate your edits with headings and dates — edit history is already tracked automatically for anyone who's curious about what was added when. Best practice is to edit the question so it reads as though all relevant information was present from the very start, rather than as a chain of multiple staged updates. This helps readers get an accurate understanding of your issue quickly.

Comment: As an update, I also tried using a new 2021.3.29f1 editor I just installed, and then I created a new project. The project has a single scene, with a camera, and then attaching the exact described behaviour. Still, did not work. In the exact same way. I'll try another major Unity version and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, I just tested in Unity 2020.3.12f1 (an older version) and it works well (both in .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4x). It seems to be a bug in whatever comes bundled in Unity 2021.3, at least in Linux/Ubuntu editor version(s).

Comment: Update: This still fails in 2022.3.0 version. Any hint will be appreciated, since the last working version so far seems to be 2020.3.x. Again: my editor in particular is the Ubuntu one.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli It sounds like you've found an Editor/engine bug, so you'll need to file a bug report with Unity.

Answer (score 2):

You specifically say that you want to use SSL/TLS encryption (`SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,`), but the protocol-part of your address is `http://`, not `https://`. Try this:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://127.0.0.1:8545");
```

Also note that you might need a self-signed SSL certificate for the local webserver in order for https to work properly.

Comment: Added more details. Forget about the SSL thing.